# Convert a Bitmap's transparent background to white

Tags: android, background, bitmap

I take a screenshot of a view (which contains a black line drawn on a white background):

```
myView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap drawing = Bitmap.createBitmap(myView.getDrawingCache());
```

If I rotate this bitmap like so:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(45);
drawing = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawing, 0, 0, drawing.getWidth(), drawing.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

I will get an image with a transparent background.

What do I have to do in order to replace the transparent color with white and not leave any artifacts? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my image consists of just black lines over a black background, I was able to work around this issue in a very inefficient manner: iterate over all the pixels in the image and replace their color with white if they are not black. It seems that there is a separation zone between Color.TRANSPARENT and Color.WHITE a few pixels wide, which will make life really hard for someone trying to achieve the same result for a more colorful image.